# When Orientation is changed effects are not applied (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, swift3, orientation

I am just trying to write code that only when the device is upside down will a label "dave" not be hidden. Right now the label "dave" is shown in all 4 orientations. This is my code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var dave: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    s()

}


func s() {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft {
        dave.isHidden = true




    } else if UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight {
        dave.isHidden = true


    } else if UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.portrait {
        dave.isHidden = true


    } else if UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.portraitUpsideDown {
        dave.isHidden = false
    }}}
```

Comment: You do know that *viewDidLoad* is fired **once**, right? Don't call your "s" function there - call it when the orientation changes. (And yes, you also want to check the initial orientation in *viewWillAppear*.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your device orientation become change then `viewWillTransition` this delegate will fire. So call your `S()` function within this method rather than `viewDidLoad`.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        s()
}
```

Hope this will help you.